# What is wrong with my route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I get the following error when I click the Edit link from the List view

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'envId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'WebUI.Controllers.EnvironmentsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters*

Here is my code:

[Summary.ascx](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/612412/)
[Routes](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/612413/)
[Env Controller, Edit Action methods](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/612415/)
[Env Controller, List Action method](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/612416/)
[EnvRepository and SqlEnvRepository](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/612417/)

Comment: I have a feeling that it depends on which URL you're trying to open...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your auto-generated links say this:

```
<td><%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id= Model.EnvironmentID} )%></td>
```

but the controller code says this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int envId)
```

MVC's model binding hooks the parameters in the action up by name, and the default route assumes the first parameter will be an `int` called `id`. Change the name of your `Edit()` parameter to `id` and it should work.

Alternatively, you could change the ActionLink parameters object to `new { envId = Model.EnvironmentID }` but that will cause your URLs to look like this:

```
http://localhost/Env/Edit?envId = 1
```

instead of this:

```
http://localhost/Env/Edit/1
```